# how does the order of if conditions work in a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the link of code image is in the comment, check it to understand my question. i can't understand what's the difference between the commented out code and the if statement right above it. aren't they the same and shouldn't result be the same? but the commented out code gives correct result and not the one above it.

```
if string != "+" or string != "-" or string != "*" or string != "/" or string != "exit":
    print("invalid input")

elif string == "+" or string == "-" or string == "*" or string == "/" or string == "exit":
    break
```

even if i pass the appropriate string it generates invalid input and asks me to enter over and over again.

```
 if string == "+" or string == "-" or string == "*" or string == "/" or string == "exit":
    break

elif string != "+" or string != "-" or string != "*" or string != "/" or string != "exit":
    print("your input is wrong, please enter again:")
```

but using the code given above provides me with correct result.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbhqu.png this is the link of code image

Comment: `string != "+" or string != "-"` is always going to give `True`, there's no point in this condition.

Comment: on the first line, you should use `and` instead of `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire code should be shortened to:

```
bannedstring = ['+', '-', '*', '/', 'exit']
if string in bannedstring:
    break
else: # Use else not elif!
    print('invalid input')
```

There should never be more than 1 `or` in a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `or` with multiple `!=` conditions. That boolean will always be true.
consider

```
string = '+'
if string != "+" or string != "-": #False or True = True
    print(string != "+") #False
    print(string != "-") #true
```

The `and` keyword fits better